# Selenium error At the end of the page

Tags: python, selenium

I have written this code using selenium python so parse a webpage(dynamically loading) so
that it goes till the end and then stop when "load more" button is not clickable anymore.

```
 wait=WebDriverWait(driver,50) 
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'bottomPager'))) while
 EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'bottomPager')):
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@id="bottomPager"]').click()
     if not driver.find_element_by_id('bottomPager').is_enabled():
        break
     wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'bottomPager')))
```

but I am getting the error when it reaches the end of the page

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python_org_search2.py", line 24, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@id="bottomPager"]').click()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 60, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 166, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (643, 628)\n  (Session info: chrome=34.0.1847.137)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)'
```

What are the changes required in code so as to rectify it ?

Comment: you are trying to click an element that is not clickable, what is the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this exception only occurs when using the Chrome driver with Selenium. Can you use Firefox instead? (I believe Firefox is the primary intended browser for webdriver invocations via Selenium.)

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

That should clear up this exception.

(You can get portable versions of Firefox at [this site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox,%20Portable%20Ed./).)

Comment: Initially, I tried with firefox but it used to hang after loading 10-12 pages using this script

Comment: Which version of Selenium and FF were you using? Can you post your full script and a link to the sites you are trying to parse?

Comment: You can call `import selenium
print selenium.__version__` to get the Selenium version, and `print driver.capabilities['version']` to get your FF driver version

Comment: selenium - 2.41.0
FF 29.0
link - http://www.healthkart.com/sports-n-fitness/sports-equipment/badminton?navKey=SCT-SPT-SE-BAD

Comment: Can you post the script you are trying to use to access this website? (You'll likely want to edit your question to do so)